# Browserify won't compile with Date lines

Tags: javascript, browserify

These two lines in my JavaScript seem to stop Browserify from compiling. The two lines are:

```
$( "#check_in" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2015,08,27), maxDate: new Date(2015,09,03) });
$( "#check_out" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2015,08,27), maxDate: new Date(2015,09,03) });
```

Does anyone know why this error out? The error I get is **Invalid number (39:61) while parsing file:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know why this error out?

A leading `0` indicates an **octal** number literal. Valid digits are 0-7. `08` is therefore invalid.

Remove leading `0`s.

Also keep in mind that `Date` uses **zero-based** months, so August would be `7`, not `8`.